# GCM does not appear to register with iOS archived app

Tags: ios, iphone, google-cloud-messaging, cocoapods

I have followed the google instructions for implementing the GCM into my iOS project. Everything works fine when running the app straight to my device but if i archive the app and install it through my local iTunes then it appears that the GCM does not register and i do not receive a token. I am struggling because i cant debug the archived app so am finding it difficult to pint point the issue.

I am not sure if it is a cocoapods issue or some sort of library issue or even a signing issue.

Does any one have any suggestions on how i could debug this. I assumed an archived version of my app would still be running the same debug version as running it straight to my device, the only thing that i think is different is the signing that is done when you archive for AdHoc.

UPDATE

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application       didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {
[self setRootViewControllerByCheckingLoginStatus];
// [START register_for_remote_notifications]
// [START_EXCLUDE]
_registrationKey = @"onRegistrationCompleted";
_messageKey = @"onMessageReceived";
// Configure the Google context: parses the GoogleService-Info.plist, and initializes
// the services that have entries in the file
NSError* configureError;
[[GGLContext sharedInstance] configureWithError:&configureError];
if (configureError != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Error configuring the Google context: %@", configureError);
}
_gcmSenderID = [[[GGLContext sharedInstance] configuration] gcmSenderID];
// [END_EXCLUDE]
// Register for remote notifications
UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
// [END register_for_remote_notifications]
// [START start_gcm_service]
[[GCMService sharedInstance] startWithConfig:[GCMConfig defaultConfig]];
// [END start_gcm_service]
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
// Handler for registration token request
_registrationHandler = ^(NSString *registrationToken, NSError *error){
    if (registrationToken != nil)
    {
        NSString *regID = registrationToken;

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: regID forKey:@"regID"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
        weakSelf.registrationToken = registrationToken;
        NSLog(@"Registration Token: %@", registrationToken);
        [weakSelf subscribeToTopic];
        NSDictionary *userInfo = @{@"registrationToken":registrationToken};
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:weakSelf.registrationKey
                                                            object:nil
                                                          userInfo:userInfo];
                    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success"
                                                            message:registrationToken
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Registration to GCM failed with error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        NSDictionary *userInfo = @{@"error":error.localizedDescription};
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:weakSelf.registrationKey
                                                            object:nil
                                                          userInfo:userInfo];
    }
};
return YES;
```

Comment: What do you mean by GCM cannot register? You can log the error that you get to some file etc. and investigate why that happens. There shouldn't be any reason it doesn't work when Archived.

Comment: You can probably make `TextView` in your app, so even it is an archive, you can still see the log information. Also, if your app is in production, you need a production APNS certificate file for your app.

Comment: I have added the code in the AppDelegate for didfinish. the _registrationHandler = doesn't run at all when archived. when running straight to the phone from xcode it is fine. it doesnt appear to be the apns not registering.

Comment: i have created the config file both production and development. archiving for ad hoc should still be development not production

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this by sending the console log to a file and then reading the file into a textView. the error i received was "No valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application on app store"

the problem turned out to be the provisioning profile. i had for some reason named it the same as my bundle ID, i am not entirely sure if that was the issue but when i created a new one it worked fine

Comment: @ztan there is still an issue. now when i archive the app i only receive push notifications when the app is in the background. if it is not running at all nothing happens and if i am in the app and receive a notification the app closes. any ideas?